# erro em cadastro de conteudo

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, post

Esta é minha primeira postagem então desculpa se fizer algo errado se eu violar alguma regra favor avisar.

minha duvida  é a seguinte:
 estou criando uma "rede social" e o código de publicação de post não esta funcionando eu utilizei o mesmo código(com outras variáveis obviamente ) para cadastro de usuário porem na hora de cadastrar ele apenas exibe a pagina php onde fica o código com query e etc... (tela que não deveria ser exibida).
segue código da pagina:

```
   <?php


// Conexão com o banco de dados

$conn = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Problemas na conexão.");
$db = @mysql_select_db("mu", $conn) or die ("Problemas na conexão");

// Se o usuário clicou no botão cadastrar efetua as ações


// Recupera os dados dos campos

$titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
$data = $_POST["data"];
$descricao = $_POST["descricao"];
// $foto= $_FILES["FOTO"];
$tipos_evento_id = $_POST["tipos_evento"];

// Se a foto estiver sido selecionada
if (!empty($foto["name"])) {

    // Largura máxima em pixels
    $largura = 150000;//coloquei um numero grande para testes
    // Altura máxima em pixels
    $altura = 180000;//coloquei um numero grande para testes
    // Tamanho máximo do arquivo em bytes
    $tamanho = 1000000000;//coloquei um numero grande para testes

    // Verifica se o arquivo é uma imagem
    if(!preg_match("/^image\/(pjpeg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|jpg)$/", $foto["type"])){
        $error[1] = "Imagem invalida";
    } 

    // Pega as dimensões da imagem
    $dimensoes = getimagesize($foto["tmp_name"]);

    // Verifica se a largura da imagem é maior que a largura permitida
    if($dimensoes[0] > $largura) {
        $error[2] = "A largura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$largura." pixels";
    }

    // Verifica se a altura da imagem é maior que a altura permitida
    if($dimensoes[1] > $altura) {
        $error[3] = "Altura da imagem não deve ultrapassar ".$altura." pixels";
    }

    // Verifica se o tamanho da imagem é maior que o tamanho permitido
    if($foto["size"] > $tamanho) {
        $error[4] = "A imagem deve ter no máximo ".$tamanho." bytes";
    }

    // Se não houver nenhum erro
    if (count($error) == 0) {

        // Pega extensão da imagem
        preg_match("/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $foto["name"], $ext);

        // Gera um nome único para a imagem
        $nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . "." . $ext[1];

        // Caminho de onde ficará a imagem
        $caminho_imagem = "fotos/" . $nome_imagem;

        // Faz o upload da imagem para seu respectivo caminho
        move_uploaded_file($foto["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);
        $foto=$caminho_imagem;



        // Insere os dados no banco
            $sql = mysql_query ("insert into `evento`(`TITULO_EVENTO`, `DATA_EVENTO`, `DESCRICAO_EVENTO`, `TIPO_EVENTO`) VALUES ('$titulo','$data','$descricao','$tipos_evento')");


        // Se os dados forem inseridos com sucesso
        if ($sql){
            echo "Você foi cadastrado com sucesso.";
            header("Location: novo_evento.php");
        }
    }

    // Se houver mensagens de erro, exibe-as
    if (count($error) != 0) {
        foreach ($error as $erro) {
            echo $erro . "<br />";
            header("Location: novo_evento.php");
        }
    }
}



 ?>
```

Comment: No SOPT, não é necessário utilizar linguagem formal, por isso editei, em relação a sua pergunta, você ligou o serviço php?

Comment: Você está criando uma rede social com funções obsoletas é isso mesmo?

Comment: Primeiro comente as linhas do `header(...);`, depois coloque esse linha e veja o erro que aparece `$sql = mysql_query ("insert into evento(TITULO_EVENTO, DATA_EVENTO, DESCRICAO_EVENTO, TIPO_EVENTO) VALUES ('$titulo','$data','$descricao','$tipos_evento')") or die(mysql_error());` pode ser o formato da data ...

Comment: Apenas uma dúvida, já tentou remover o espaço em branco antes da tag `<?php`?

Comment: Rede social? Olhe Ratchet - PHP , Socket.io e Nodejs. Dessa forma voce vai trabalhar bastante